# Firebase Functions take 1 second to start any function

Tags: performance, function, firebase, profiling

I have a Firebase function. It makes 3 simple calls to Firebase Database.
I put some logs to profile a little, ran function 5 times to ensure it is not a cold start and here is what I get on 6th run:

```
8:10:34.133 am - Function execution started
8:10:34.133 am - Billing account not configured.....
8:10:35.284 am - MyFunction start and make 3 database calls
8:10:35.456 am - MyFunction database results obtained
8:10:35.461 am - MyFunction execution finished
```

So, it takes just 250ms to make database calls, but

It takes almost 1 second from the alleged function start to the execution of the first line.

My question is – is it really the case, which would make Firebase Functions unusable for a serverless API, or I am doing something wrong?

Function is an https trigger. Written with Express. Only CORS is applied.
Setup for functions:

```
const unsecure = express();
unsecure.get("/myFunc", require("./core/myFunc.f.js"))
```

MyFunc.f.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
try {
    admin.initializeApp(
        Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, {
            credential: admin.credential.cert(
            ),
            storageBucket: ""
        })
    );
} catch (e) {
    //can be initialized only once
}
const database = admin.database()

module.exports = (request, response) => {
    console.log("/myFunc started and calling database")
    Promise.all([
        database.ref("database_node").child("default").once("value"),
        database.ref("database_node").child("no_code").once("value"),
        database.ref("database_node").child("test_code").once("value")
    ]).then(values => {
        console.log("/myFunc got database results: " + JSON.stringify(values))

        response.status(200).send({})
    })
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DougStevenson edited. Question is if I have a bug that slows down my performance or I was wrong to assume I can write a serverless API with Firebase Functions

Comment: You did just write a [serverless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) API with Cloud Functions for Firebase.  Also realize that Cloud Functions is in beta and there are no guarantees for performance or uptime.

Comment: So basically what you are saying – Firebase Cloud Functions are not for production use because it's in beta?

Comment: @DougStevenson Doug, this is an issue that's been brought up on numerous occasions across SO and github. Namely that cloud function execution times (both warm and cold) are inconsistent and much slower than, for instance, AWS lambda. So much so that it's making their use in customer-facing situations untenable.I appreciate that it's in "beta", but that has been the case for a long time now, and you will start losing some of us early-adopters if you can't provide some reassurance on how the response time will evolve over the coming months/years.

Comment: @HarryMexican Feel free to voice your concerns on firebase-talk.  Stack Overflow isn't exactly the right place for it.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk